# How to apply limit of 2 lines for UILabel ,ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am creating an app in Swift. I am having an UILabel with dynamic data. I want to apply restriction of two lines to that UILabel i.e. it should do word wrapping and show text in just 2 lines only. Any solution will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

set

**Programmatically**

**Objective-C**

```
titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
[titleLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

**Swift**

```
titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping

titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2

// titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0                      //'0' means infinite number of lines
```

**Inspector attribute**

[image]

Comment: if you want to set text fit use **titleLabel.sizeToFit()** also

Answer (score 3):

If you want to set if from storyboard then select your label go to Attribute Inspector and set lines to 2 and set line breaks to Word Wrap as shown in below image:

[image]